# What does "SDF" stand for in Robotech?

Tags: robotech

I knew that the *Robotech* series was adapted from three other anime: *The Super Dimension Fortress Macross*, *Super Dimension Cavalry Southern Cross*, and *Genesis Climber MOSPEADA*. However, I always thought that when it came to the "SDF-#" it was either referring to "Space Defense Fortress" or "Space Defense Force".

However, when I was watching Episode 78 ("Ghost Town"), the old guys referred to the crash warship as a "Super Dimensional Fortress".

What does "SDF" actually mean in *Robotech*?

Comment: Is there some reason you thought SDF might mean "Space Defense Fortress" or "Space Defense Force"? I haven't seen the show, but unless the show references either of those terms, it seems pretty obvious that SDF stands for "Super Dimension Fortress".

Comment: @senshin they dont actually say Super Dimension Fortress until episode 78 in the third season to my knowledge and SDF is commonly used as Space Defense Force but since it was a warship that only ever got that name i thought fortress, maybe it was a bad assumption

Comment: @MemorX Ah, I see. I suppose that could cause some confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Robotech Saga wikia](http://robotech.wikia.com/wiki/Super_Dimensional_Fortress), "SDF" in the "SDF-#" stands for **Super Dimensional Fortress**.